# ImproperlyConfigured at / 'ClientEventLogAdmin.exclude' refers to field 'created' that is missing from the form

Tags: python, django

I am installing a django application module.I am getting this error.
I started another MicroInstance and reinstalled everything but still I am getting this error.
.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://54.235.127.252/mds/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['sana.mrs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'sana.mrs.util.LoggingMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/sana/urls.py" in <module>
  12. admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  26.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/sana/mrs/admin.py" in <module>
  26. admin.site.register(ClientEventLog, ClientEventLogAdmin)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in register
  97.             validate(admin_class, model)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in validate
  24.     validate_base(cls, model)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in validate_base
  279.             check_formfield(cls, model, opts, 'exclude', field)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in check_formfield
  369.                 "is missing from the form." % (cls.__name__, label, field))

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /
Exception Value: 'ClientEventLogAdmin.exclude' refers to field 'created' that is missing from the form.
```

Note:I just need to install this application.I am intermediate in python.and beginner in Django.But professional in PHP,mysql and front end with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, the problem is likely to be related to the `moca` framework.

If your `/opt/sana/mrs/admin.py` file looks like [this](http://code.google.com/p/moca/source/browse/servers/mds/branches/trunk/sana/mrs/admin.py?spec=svn994&r=994) then the culprit is likely to be located at [line 12](http://code.google.com/p/moca/source/browse/servers/mds/branches/trunk/sana/mrs/admin.py?spec=svn994&r=994#12) : the `created` field is refered in the exclude list, but not previously defined.

As I'm not sure about your needs here are some solutions you can try :

- Re-install or update your `moca` frameword ;
- Add a piece of code before the execute definition (not sure what's type it should be though) :

  ```
  from django.db import models # You may also place it in the top of the file
  created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  ```
- Remove the `created` item from the `exclude` list (not sure about the impact though)

Hope it helps,

Comment: 1.I tried reinstalling then I am getting same error 2.I tried 2nd step then I am getting NameError

Comment: What is the complete stacktrace of your NameError ?

Comment: I missed to import the `DateField` type... I've updated my answer
(But I'm not sure if it's the right type though)

Comment: there is no class DateField anywhere .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24234/discussion-between-y-and-madhu13)